# Native Android: Create dynamically a grid-like scrollable layout with equal width buttons

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a layout as per this picture (paint'ed).

[Layout Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shsCF.png)

Target level is API 17. This has to be created programmatically, not using XML. This has to be a responsive design.

I extensively researched and attempted other partially similar situations on stackoverflow, using GridLayout, TableLayout, GridView, various layout parameters, gravity, weight, view nesting and so on. However,

(a) I can't get the text buttons width to fill the available width real estate as per device screen size and orientation. Buttons with shorter texts are coming with shorter width.

(b) The plus, minus and number buttons are of fixed height and width irrespective of screen sizes and orientation. But they are not aligning with the text button in the left on the same row. only the bottom few pixels are visible.

I would appreciate any code snippet that can achieve the above layout. Thanks a million.

UPDATE:

Following inputs from @tiny-sunlight, I did this. Next I will recreate this programmatically.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutTable"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutRow"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="17"
                android:text="This is my button"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />
            <Button
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="-"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />
            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="+"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I think using a xml is same as creating  programmatically.

Comment: I will know the number of rows and content of rows only at runtime. So xml doesn't help, right?

I like the RecyclerView idea from @rusheel-jain below. Maybe I will use that in the next iteration.

Thank you both for your prompt replies.

Comment: Yes.RecyclerView is better choice and the item of RecyclerView is xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to build layout below programmatically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1111"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="#44bb11"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="11"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />
            <ImageView
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Following your clue, I did this for testing. Next I will try to recreate this programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recycler view, which will provide you scrolling option plus bind views on the fly for you.

So load a linear layout (orientation horizonal) into the recycler view. now for the layout, it then becomes easier. You need a textview, button,textview,button.
For each of these textview and buttons, set widht = 0dp and weight as 7,1,1,1 respectively i.e. your leftmost textview occupy 70% of width whereas all other occupy 10%. Obviously you can change these weights as per your requirements. Thats it for the layout.

Now just fill your data using the adapter.